# Adding WCF reference to web app can't find endpoint in config?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

UPDATE: I got this exact same config to work from another web server. Any thoughts on why it works for one but not the other?

I have an MVC web app that i am trying to add a WCF service reference to. The WCF service is sitting on a web server and i can pull up the service in the browser ( you created a service) default page. The test client in VS for WCF also works with the service. I am getting the below error when trying to add the reference...

> There was no endpoint listening at that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.

Here is my service config model...

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Basic" sendTimeout="12:00:00" receiveTimeout="12:00:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="TSRBehavior" name="TechnologyServiceRequestWCF.TSRWebService">
    <endpoint address="~/TSRWebService.svc"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="Basic"
              name="Basic"
              contract="TechnologyServiceRequestWCF.ITSRWebService" />
    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              name="Metadata"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="TSRBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="24:00:00"/>
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentInstances="100" maxConcurrentSessions="100"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

There is no client config yet since the reference auto generates that for you after successfully talking to the service.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the mex endpoint and change the line

includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" 
by
serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"

Comment: could be the possible cause for it work on one webserver and not the other? If so, can you tell me why that attribute would cause that? Just like to understand why to do it :)

Comment: so you could see the error because that gives errors wcf

Comment: I'll give this a shot and see!

Comment: Just ran this update but still got the error. "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Answer (score 0):

My configuration had nothing wrong for those looking for a simple config that should work for most! My issue ended up being a porting issue to bypass firewalls. So nothing wrong on my end. :)